# Unable to use Proc/lambda returned from method in select/reject filters in Ruby

Tags: ruby, lambda, bitcoin

I am unable to use the Proc returned by `valid_transaction` as argument in the select filter, any ideas why? I am able to do this when writing methods without classes.

```
require 'json'

module Electrum
  class History
    def self.valid_transaction
      lambda { |tx| tx["date"] == "----" }
    end

    def self.list
      JSON::parse `electrum history`
    end

    def self.confirmed
      list.reject { |tx| tx["date"] == "----" }
    end

    def self.unconfirmed
      list.select(&:valid_transaction)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This question could be improved by removing self.confirmed, since it isn't needed to show the problem you are having.  It would also be helpful to give the reader a starting place: "When I call `Elecrum::History.unconfirmed`, I get this syntax error:..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the colon:

```
list.select(&valid_transaction)
```

The & syntax is used to pass a lambda or proc to a method that is expecting a block.  That's what you need here.

With a colon, the effect is somewhat different:

```
list.select(&:valid_transaction)
```

is equivalent to this:

```
list.select { |tx| tx.valid_transaction }
```

Which is not what you intend at all.

The reason the colon has this affect is that Ruby calls #to_proc on the `&` argument.  A symbol (which is what `:valid_transaction` is) responds to #to_proc by creating a proc that calls the method named by the symbol.

Comment: Thanks! I had understood it wrong! So, now I can even supply variables, I can't believe I didn't know this :)

Comment: "With a colon, Ruby tries to do something different." – That's misleading. They are, in fact, the same thing. People treat `&:whatever` as some black magic, but it is not. Saying `foo(&bar)` means "call method `foo` passing the `Proc` returned by evaluating `bar` as if it was supplied as a block; and if the object isn't a `Proc` already, call `to_proc` first". `Hash`, `Symbol` and `Method`, for example, implement `to_proc`, and [I argued that `Array` and `Set` should do so as well](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11262#change-59342).

Comment: @JörgWMittag The are indeed the same thing.  I was deliberately eliding the details, but I guess I could have worded it better.